# Using Realm, and JavaScript how do I access data in Atlas

Tags: javascript, realm

I am attempting to incorporate Realm into a mobile app and am able to successfully use authentication:

---

```
App.jsx
...
export default AppWrapper = () => {
  return (
    <AppProvider id={"devicesync - xxxxx"}>
      <RealmProvider>
        <ContextProvider>
          <App />
        </ContextProvider>
      </RealmProvider>
    </AppProvider>
  );
};
...
```

---

---

Realm.jsx

```
import Realm from "realm";

Realm.flags.THROW_ON_GLOBAL_REALM = true;

const app = new Realm.App({ id: "devicesync-xxxxx" });

export default app;
```

---

---

This is my model:

```
import Realm from "realm";

export class ProjectSchema extends Realm.Object {
  static primaryKey = "_id";
  static schema = {
    name: "Project",
    primaryKey: "_id",
    properties: {
      _id: "uuid",
      area: "string",
      customer: "string",
      customercontact: "string",
      rigcompany: "string",
      projectname: "string",
      description: "string",
      projectedstartdate: "date",
      actualstartdate: "date",
      expectedduration: "int",
      actualduration: "int",
      status: "string",
      statusdate: "date",
      comment: "string",
      latdec: "double",
      longdec: "double",
    },
  };
}
```

---

---

Here is my partial code to access the data:

```
...
import { Realm, useQuery, useRealm } from "realm";
import Project from "../models/projectModel";

const ActiveProjects = () => {
  const [activeProjects, setActiveProjects] = useState([]);

  const projectList = useQuery(Project);
  console.log("projectList", projectList);
...
```

---

I get the following error when trying to access data in Atlas:
_realm.useQuery is not a function

Comment: Is this react? If not, what is the complete platform